# jQuery Mobile - How to change page behaviour depending on previous page

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile

I have three pages in my app: #main, #new and #existing.

Everytime #new is loaded, I want it to detect if it came from #menu or #existing. Depending on this information it should either do nothing or populate its form.

How can I achieve this both in terms of the right command for previous page and handling the DOM correctly?

Comment: is `#main` a page (separate file) or an element/container?

Comment: Need some code to play with. Create a JSFiddle please!

Comment: #main is a page defined in HTML, all of them are. I will create a JSFiddle right away.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/rysfM/7/ Here it is. The save button doesn't work because of the condition I am trying to do. If you remove the if statmenent you can save and load "patients".

Comment: Aha! So they're **not** pages ;-)

Comment: There are many ways to achieve this, you can do this for example `$(document).on('pagehide', function () { alert($(this).attr('id')); });`

Comment: Why on pagehide? I want it to behave differently everytime it is loaded, shouldn't I use pageinit?

Comment: This to determine the id of previous page. Save the id in a var and on pagebeforeshow, do what you want based on the id in var. or you can use pagebeforechange and check data.fromPage and data.toPage

Comment: have you found a solution for this?

Answer (score 2):

According to your # these pages need to be dom elements. Just use the variable in javascript and check this in every step.

- Create a new variable like *lastPage*
- On every click, I prefer to use *data-foo* like HTML5 data attribute.
- Change *lastPage* according to navigation.
- And do after that what you really want.

  ```
   var lastPage = '';

   /* This code from jQuery Mobile, link is below the code. */

   // Define a click binding for all anchors in the page
   $( "a" ).on( "click", function( event ){
       // Prevent the usual navigation behavior
       event.preventDefault();
       // Alter the url according to the anchor's href attribute, and
       // store the data-foo attribute information with the url
   $.mobile.navigate( this.attr( "href" ), {
       lastPage: this.attr("data-foo") // store data here
   });
   // Hypothetical content alteration based on the url. E.g, make
   // an AJAX request for JSON data and render a template into the page.
       alterContent( this.attr("href") );
   });
  ```

**HTML Example**

```
<a href="foo.bar" data-foo="main">Main Page</a>
<a href="foo.bar" data-foo="new">New Page</a>
<a href="foo.bar" data-foo="existing">Existing Page</a>
```

You can make data-anythingyouwant. Only the data is important, after that you can use everything. It just an HTML5 DOM attribute.

*Edit:*

I suggest you to check navigation page. You can understand better the concept after that.
Code Source: http://view.jquerymobile.com/1.3.2/dist/demos/widgets/navigation/

Comment: Your answer is too vague.

Comment: Now it makes sense. Provide a demo if you can, it will help understanding your solution.

Answer (score 1):

Take advantage of jQuery-Mobile page events, such as `pagebeforehide` and `pageshow`.

> **[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Palestinian/WpMzH/)**

Store current page's `id` before navigating away.

```
var prevPage;

$(document).on('pagebeforehide', function () {
  prevPage = $.mobile.activePage[0].id;
});
```

When destination page is active, retrieve the stored previous page `id`.

```
$(document).on('pageshow', function () {
  $(this).find('.destination').text('Previous Page: ' + prevPage);
});
```